# My Python code that writes to a specific line sometimes doesn't work

Tags: python, file

I've written some code to write to a specific line in a file, but sometimes it will overwrite everything

```
def read_write_file(file1, text, line_no):
    lines = []
    with open(file1, 'r+') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == line_no:
                if line != text:
                    line = text
            lines.append(line)

    with open(file1, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
```

The fie I'm trying to write to willl look something like.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

I want to add text in between app = Flask(**name**) & if **name**=='**main**':
        app.run(), sometimes it will add the text without overwriting anything but sometimes when I run it, will delete everything after app = Flask(**name**).

Comment: Sounds like the code is raising an exception during the write phase. It could be that `text` is not the string you think it is or that there is some problem with `text` being a unicode string that doesn't encode correctly. Do you see an exception? Does your code suppress exceptions?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not getting an exception error and I encoded the string to be utf-8, it just deletes all the text after the line I specify to write to, but sometimes it just writes to the line without deleting anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing to a tempfile and doing a `shutil.move`, all you need it the line preceding the line where you want to insert:

```
def read_write_file(file1, start, to_insrt):
    from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
    from shutil import move
    with open(file1) as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
        for line in f:
            tmp.write(line)
            if line.rstrip() == start:
                tmp.write(to_insrt+"\n")
        move(tmp.name, file1)
```

Demo:

```
In [4]: cat test.txt
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
In [5]: read_write_file("test.txt","app = Flask(__name__)","print('hello world')")

In [6]: cat test.txt
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
print('hello world')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

In your own code you open with `'r+'` which is for reading and writing, you never write until you reopen so there is no point, you could also end up with lines like `print('hello world')print('hello world')` unless you add newlines and even then you could end up with incorrect data especially if you are writing python code.  Also if you are using enumerate starting to count lines from 1 you should set `1` as the start with enumerate or you will get off by one errors.

Comment: Thankyou but I need to to post it a specific line because I will keep adding new lines to it.

Comment: @EricMacLeod, you can still keep the enumerate logic but I don't see how adding more lines is going to be an issue as is.